# headings in org-mode: unexpected behavior

Tags: org-mode

Recently, I started experiencing unexpected behavior when editing org-mode files.

Suppose I have two headings, with _ indicating the cursor position.

```
* Heading
*_
** Subheading
```

I want to insert a new subheading before the existing one.  So I now press * to get a second asterisk.  But I don't get a second *.  Instead, one of the asterisks from the existing subheading on the line below disappears!  Then I press * again, and now the asterisk reappears!  Now I press * for a third time, and I finally get the second asterisk on the new heading that I want to insert.  So I press space to give it a title, only to find that I now have four asterisks!  Like this:

```
* Heading
**** _ 
** Subheading
```

I find this behavior extremely annoying and have no idea how it is supposed to be helpful or what purpose it serves.  I don't think I changed anything in my setup, so it might have been enabled by an update.  I want to turn it off, but I can't find the relevant variable (meaning I don't even know what to search for).  Does anyone know how to turn this "feature" off?

Comment: Does it happen if you start with `emacs -q`? If not, there is something in your init file causing this: bisect it to figure out what's doing it. FWIW, I cannot reproduce it in Org mode 9.4.4.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**

I found this is a [known bug](https://orgmode.org/list/87sgbvjqos.fsf@gnu.org/) in org-mode.  The problem is setting `org-hide-emphasis-markers` to t.  Once it's set back to nil (the default), the problem goes away.  It is because org tries to hide the strong emphasis marker, **.

I reported my finding to the org mailing list.

Comment: Yes, you are right.